# Python 3 scripts, html

Tags: html, python

Пожалуйста помогите! Вот как 2 день как я изучаю питон, и меня возник вопрос.
Я написал код которий через консоль производит "регистрацию" и позже можно логинится в всё той же консоли. И вот суть вопроса, можно ли как то этот код подключить к простой html странице где будет несколько кнопок и полей для заполнения, грубо говоря интерфейс (чтобы так же можна было регистрироватся и логинится)?

Comment: Вам нужен CGI-сервер. [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html)

Comment: И только? Не будет нужен SQL или что-то в этом духе?

Comment: SQL - это база данных (точнее тип). Если Вам требуется сохранять пользователей после регистрации, то понадобится. Но на первое время можно обойтись обычными `*.txt` файлами. Тут всё на Ваше усмотрение.

Comment: А как сохранять в `*.txt`? Могли бы предоставить документацию, буду очень благодарен?

Comment: `f = open('text.txt', 'w'); f.write('Some string'); f.close()`